# Android Studio stopped recognizing my Redmi as an Android device

Tags: android-studio, devise

I normally use my Redmi 7A to test the applications that I make with Android Studio, but suddenly Android Studio stopped recognizing it as an Android device and only shows it as a USB device, I tried restarting both the pc and the mobile, deactivate and activate the debugging mode, and it should not be a driver problem because until a few days ago I could run the applications perfectly on my device. Additionally I tried to connect two more devices of different brands in debugging mode and it did not recognize them either, someone could tell me what happened with the IDE and how to fix it.[An image of what Android Studio shows me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPmBj.jpg)